# Server Side Includes: variable in <!--#if not found, #echo prints content

Tags: html, apache, debian, server-side-includes

I want to check if a file exists with `<!--#if expr='-F %{foo}' -->` but apaches error.log says the variable wouldn't exist. `<!--#echo var="foo" -->` works fine.

I started in a file with hard coded values where it worked fine. Now I want to create a parameterized snippet I can include in several other files.

```
<!--#set var="foo" value="/path/to/file" -->

<!--#echo var="foo" --><br>

<!--#if expr='-F %{foo}' -->
exists<br>
<!--#else -->
doesn't exist<br>
<!--#endif -->

<!--#echo var="foo" -->
```

I'd expect the output

```
/path/to/file
exists
/path/to/file
```

but instead I get the error message saying that the variable wouldn't exist in apaches error.log:

AH01337: Could not parse expr `"-F %{foo}"`: Variable 'foo' does not exist

<sub>it's not so 01337 if you'd ask me...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at the [mod_include documentation about flow control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#flowctrl) and the [Apache Expressions Syntax](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) shows two things which might interfere here and cause this issue:

- The examples in the [mod_include documentation about flow control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#flowctrl) use the `v("foo")` syntax and not the `%{foo}` syntax to refer to variables (unless `SSILegacyExprParser` is set to `on`, but the legacy syntax seems to be `$foo` anyways).
- The [Apache Expressions Syntax](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) suggests that only [a fixed list of server-set variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars) are usable with the `%{…}` syntax.

So I assume that there are two different types of variables and only one (the server-provided variables) can be used with the `%{…}` syntax. (And yes, these different ways to refer to a variable look confusing to me, too.)